# Possible bug in Sympy library working with imaginary numbers when there are not any

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods

I tried to code *regula falsi* method in python using Sympy library, however with certain functions I get an issue telling I'm working with imaginary numbers.

This is my code:

```
def reglaFalsa(fx,p0,p1,tolerancia,iteracionesMaximas):

    fx = S(fx)
    i = 2
    q0 = fx.subs(x,p0)
    q1 = fx.subs(x,p1)


    while i<=iteracionesMaximas:
        p = p1 - q1*(p1-p0)/(q1-q0)
        if absolute(p-p1) < tolerancia:
            return p

        q = fx.subs(x,p)

        if (q**q1) < 0:
            p0 = p
            q0 = q
        else:
            p1 = p
            q1 = q
        i+= 1
    return p
```

I called this with following arguments:

`fx =3*x+sin(x)-2.71828182846**x, po=0.0, p1=2.0, tolerancia=.0001, iteracionesMaximas=15`

and

`fx =2*x**2+x-1, po=0.0, p1=1.0, tolerancia=.0001, iteracionesMaximas=15`

For `sin(x)` as argument I get `NaN` at some variables when SHOULDN'T

I'm getting following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../Prácticas/python/ReglaFalsa.py", line 16, in <module>
    print json.dumps(reglaFalsa(y,a,b,tolerancia,iteracionesMaximas), indent=1)
  File "/home/diegoaguilar/Copy/buap/Métodos/Prácticas/python/reglafalsa.py", line 45, in reglaFalsa
    if (q**q1) < 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/decorators.py", line 77, in __sympifyit_wrapper
    return func(a, b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 248, in __lt__
    raise TypeError("Invalid comparison of complex %s" % dif)
TypeError: Invalid comparison of complex 0.0114119631147945 - 0.179219618952309*
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the exponentiation (leading to complex results)

```
q**q1 < 0:
```

to multiplication

```
q*q1 < 0:
```

Or find another way to compare the signs. C, for instance, has the signbit function.

Comment: Yeah! I saw it time after. Btw, what do you mean exactly by `C`?

Comment: C, as in the programming language. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/signbit.html. Does not exist in Java, but one can compare without multiplication `if((q1>0)==(q>0))`, but one needs to discuss the border cases when `q==0`, and more urgently, the first values of q0 and q1. Check that the method deteriorates to the secant method if q0 and q1 have the same sign.

Comment: Also, your code is incomplete in the testing conditions. The solution is also found `if absolute(p-p0) < tolerancia` and `if absolute(q) < tolerancia`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `or` instead of `if`?

Comment: If you want all three cases in one condition, yes, you would connect them with `or`.